# WebApi Lambda with DataModel and Entitiy

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a WebAPI I am creating that returns all values when called by `/api/mediareleases` but I want to add a `QueryString` so that I can pull more specific data.

### Data model

```
public partial class PressReleases
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PostDateShown { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public IEnumerable<PressReleases> Get()
{
    using (MediaReleasesEntities entities = new MediaReleasesEntities())
    {
        //returns every release
        return entities.PressReleases.ToList();
    }
}

public PressReleases Get(string criteria)
{
    using (MediaReleasesEntities entities = new MediaReleasesEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            //try to convert it to date
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(criteria);

            //do something    
        }
        catch
        {
            //search by description
            return entities.PressReleases.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ShortDescription.Contains(criteria)); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am wanting to either get a date and search for the date or search the description for a keyword. This currently works but I am only returning one value. I've tried using the `Select()` or `All()` in my lambda but that just returns syntax issues. How can I return every release that contains my criteria (the word "meeting")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` as name implies will return the first record found or null

To return all results you should use the below LINQ statement

```
return entities.PressReleases.Where(e => e.ShortDescription.Contains(criteria)).ToList();
```

`.Where()` to specify our filter condition and `.ToList()` to execute against our database and return the results

And now since you're returning a List you must update your method signature to reflect the correct return type

```
public List<PressReleases> Get(string criteria)
```

Comment: I did try that, it throws the error `cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<AppApi.PressReleases> to AppApi.PressReleases`.

Comment: I completely overlooked that although it was right there in the error message. Was too focused on the lambda. Will mark as the answer, thank!